# iptables - POSTROUTING / SNAT doesn't change source IP (two routing tables)

Tags: iptables, routing, openvpn

I have a problem with iptables POSTROUTING rule, it seems that SNAT rule doesn't change source IP address. I would like set up the following system to route all traffic from LAN 2 through a VPN tunnel. **System has two routing tables** configured.

### System configuration

```
              +-----------------+
  LAN 2 ----> |eth1       eth0  +-----> LAN 1 ---> Gateway ---> Internet
              |           tun1  |
              +-------------|---+
                            `--------------- VPN tunnel ------>
```

### iptables / routing configuration

- iptables

  ```
  root@misio:~# iptables -n -L --line-numbers -v -t nat
  Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
  num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

  Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
  num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

  Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 1 packets, 122 bytes)
  num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

  Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 1 packets, 122 bytes)
  num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  1        0     0 SNAT       all  --  *      *       192.168.124.0/24     0.0.0.0/0            to:192.168.124.1
  ```
- routing (two routing tables)

  ```
  root@misio:~# ip route list
  default via 192.168.123.1 dev eth0 
  192.168.123.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.123.3 

  root@misio:~# ip route list table frankenjura
  default via 10.10.11.4 dev tun1 
  10.10.11.0/24 dev tun1  scope link 
  192.168.124.0/24 dev eth1  scope link 

  root@misio:~# ip rule
  0:      from all lookup local 
  32761:  from 192.168.124.0/24 lookup frankenjura 
  32762:  from all to 192.168.124.0/24 lookup frankenjura 
  32766:  from all lookup main 
  32767:  from all lookup default
  ```

### Investigation

- Input (eth1) - system is receiving packets from the hosts in LAN 2 (192.168.124.17):

  ```
  root@misio:~# tcpdump -n -i eth1 icmp and host 8.8.8.8
  tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
  listening on eth1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes 
  12:39:25.134315 IP 192.168.124.17 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 1181, length 40
  12:39:30.142011 IP 192.168.124.17 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 1182, length 40
  ```
- Output (tun1) - packets are routed to the correct interface (tun1), **but the source IP address is not changed**:

  ```
  root@misio:~# tcpdump -n -i tun1 icmp and host 8.8.8.8 
  tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
  listening on tun1, link-type RAW (Raw IP), capture size 262144 bytes
  12:40:20.140953 IP 192.168.124.17 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 1192, length 40
  12:40:25.148605 IP 192.168.124.17 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 1193, length 40
  ```
- ...but number of packets/bytes for the following rule doesn't increment!

  ```
  Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 1 packets, 122 bytes)
  num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  1        0     0 SNAT       all  --  *      *       192.168.124.0/24     0.0.0.0/0            to:192.168.124.1
  ```

IP tables version: 1.4.21

Would you be so kind to help, please?

## EDIT 2016-07-15

I set up iptables logging in all chains and learned that packets don't go through NAT table at all!

packets go through:
- raw (PREROUTING)
- mangle (PREROUTING)
- filter (FORWARD)
- mangle (POSTROUTING)

```
Jul 15 12:36:04 misio kernel: [ 7913.969872] raw-PRE IN=eth1 OUT= MAC=00:1e:2a:49:9d:ad:00:17:a4:da:13:09:08:00 SRC=192.168.124.17 DST=8.8.8.8 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=7668 PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=1 SEQ=1022
Jul 15 12:36:04 misio kernel: [ 7913.969894] mangle-PRE IN=eth1 OUT= MAC=00:1e:2a:49:9d:ad:00:17:a4:da:13:09:08:00 SRC=192.168.124.17 DST=8.8.8.8 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=7668 PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=1 SEQ=1022 
Jul 15 12:36:04 misio kernel: [ 7913.969908] filter-FW IN=eth1 OUT=tun1 MAC=00:1e:2a:49:9d:ad:00:17:a4:da:13:09:08:00 SRC=192.168.124.17 DST=8.8.8.8 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=127 ID=7668 PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=1 SEQ=1022 
Jul 15 12:36:04 misio kernel: [ 7913.969914] mangle-POST IN= OUT=tun1 SRC=192.168.124.17 DST=8.8.8.8 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=127 ID=7668 PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=1 SEQ=1022
```

Kind regards,
Grzegorz

Comment: I don't get what's the point doing what you're trying to do: your VPN network is `10.10.11.0/24` so I'd expect you to have `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun1 -j SNAT --to-source 10.10.11.N` where , `10.10.11.N` is what `ip addr show tun1` displays; otherwise these packets will be "martian" to the other end of the tunnel.

Comment: One more thing: I have OpenVPN deployed on several servers (to connect branch offices with the main one and between each other) and never had the need to SNAT/MASQUERADE the IPs of the servers: OpenVPN just forwards traffic between the connected networks, so you merely need to have correct `ip route` (and possible OpenVPN's own `iroute`) rules in place.  What real (original) problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately it hasn't solved a problem.
I added rule suggested by you, but it's also not increment for the traffic from incoming to eth1. So iptables don't apply it to them.

I am trying to achieve the following solution:
(1) all packets from LAN1 (eth0) should go through default route in LAN1
(2) all packets from LAN2 (eth1) should go through a OpenVPN tunnel (tun1).